# iOS: Core Animation UIView flip. How to make two turnover?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I made CATransition animation, I have 2 UIView that flips. Code below makes one turnover, how can I make 2 turnovers? Show me example please. Here is my flip code:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.startProgress = 0;
transition.endProgress = 1.0;
transition.type =@"flip";// kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = @"fromRight"; //kCATransitionFromRight;
transition.duration = 0.3;



// Add the transition animation to both layers
[self.fitstUIView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transition"];
[self.secondUIView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transition"];
```

Think of it like this is a coin that flips in the air.

EDIT

I also want that first flip was much faster than the second flip. Some kind of slow effect.

My code doing things fine for one spin, but trouble is that if I just add this transition to layer more than once, spin will be only once. So, I need to nest CATransitions to one (CAAnimation group? can't make this thing to work for me) and add with add animation method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting:

```
transition.repeatCount = 2;
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: yes this helps but I forgot valuable info, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

How about using nested animation blocks to acheive this. Something like this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:VIEW_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO_ANIMATE duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{

    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [UIView transitionWithView:VIEW_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO_ANIMATE duration:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{

         } completion:^(BOOL finished)
          {


          }];

     }];
```

Comment: look nice, but I didn't make this with blocks =( Maybe this my bad and it might be implemented with blocks. I'll edit my question a little bit about trouble that encounter with my code.